# Make every row same length and fill in missing data with ""

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am very new to Pandas. I have some json that I am trying to convert to csv rows with Pandas:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import json

data = json.dumps({
  "symbol": "AAPL",
  "financials": [{
      "date": "2019-09-28",
      #"Revenue": "2.60174e+11",
      "EPS": "11.97",
    },
    {
      "date": "2018-09-29",
      "Revenue": "2.65595e+11",
      "EPS": "12.01",
    },
    {
      "date": "2017-09-30",
     # "Revenue": "2.29234e+11",
     # "EPS": "9.27",
    },
    {
      "date": "2016-09-24",
      "Revenue": "2.15639e+11",
     # "EPS": "8.35",
    },
    {
      "date": "2015-09-26",
      "Revenue": "2.33715e+11",
      "EPS": "9.28",
    },
    {
      "date": "2014-09-27",
      "Revenue": "1.82795e+11",
      "EPS": "6.49",
    },
    {
      "date": "2013-09-28",
      "Revenue": "1.7091e+11",
      "EPS": "40.03",
    },
    {
      "date": "2012-09-29",
      "Revenue": "1.56508e+11",
      "EPS": "44.64",
    },
    {
      "date": "2011-09-24",
      "Revenue": "1.08249e+11",
      "EPS": "28.05",
    },
    {
      "date": "2010-09-25",
      "Revenue": "65225000000.0",
      "EPS": "15.41",
    },
    {
      "date": "2009-09-26",
      "Revenue": "42905000000.0",
      "EPS": "1.317",
    }
  ]
})

df = pd.read_json(data)
c = df.to_csv(index=False,na_rep=" ")
print c
```

I've commented out some items in my json to simulate missing data. But, it gives me inconsistent output for each row, especially for nested json (where I'd like to fill in missing key/value pairs with ""):

```
financials,symbol
"{u'date': u'2019-09-28', u'EPS': u'11.97'}",AAPL
"{u'date': u'2018-09-29', u'EPS': u'12.01', u'Revenue': u'2.65595e+11'}",AAPL
{u'date': u'2017-09-30'},AAPL
"{u'date': u'2016-09-24', u'Revenue': u'2.15639e+11'}",AAPL
"{u'date': u'2015-09-26', u'EPS': u'9.28', u'Revenue': u'2.33715e+11'}",AAPL
"{u'date': u'2014-09-27', u'EPS': u'6.49', u'Revenue': u'1.82795e+11'}",AAPL
"{u'date': u'2013-09-28', u'EPS': u'40.03', u'Revenue': u'1.7091e+11'}",AAPL
"{u'date': u'2012-09-29', u'EPS': u'44.64', u'Revenue': u'1.56508e+11'}",AAPL
"{u'date': u'2011-09-24', u'EPS': u'28.05', u'Revenue': u'1.08249e+11'}",AAPL
"{u'date': u'2010-09-25', u'EPS': u'15.41', u'Revenue': u'65225000000.0'}",AAPL
"{u'date': u'2009-09-26', u'EPS': u'1.317', u'Revenue': u'42905000000.0'}",AAPL
```

The other issue is that "AAPL" gets repeated for each row....I'd like to just have AAPL on the first row and get replaced with "" in the other rows. How do I achieve both of these goals so that each row is the same length?

EDIT: My json is gonna be arbitrary, since this will be a general purpose parser. So, I need it to handle a broad range of scenarios but, in the end, need it to return equal-length rows with any data missing filled in with a blank value. For this case, I'd like the following:

```
symbol,financials.date,financials.EPS,financials.Revenue
AAPL,2019-09-28,11.97,
,2018-09-29,12.01,2.65595e+11
,2017-09-30,,
,2016-09-24,,2.15639e+11
,2015-09-26,9.28,2.33715e+11
,2014-09-27,6.49,1.82795e+11
,2013-09-28,40.03,1.7091e+11
,2012-09-29,44.64,1.56508e+11
,2011-09-24,28.05,1.08249e+11
,2010-09-25,15.41,65225000000.0
,2009-09-26,1.317,42905000000.0
```

Comment: Threw an answer up that may explain the behavior. If you can give an example of the output you're expecting, I may be able to answer better.

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Updated answer

Given the new requirements, you'll have to do a bit of data transformation to get what you need. The following gives the desired output.

```py
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(data["financials"])

symbol = list(data)[0]
first_column = [data[symbol], *["" for i in range(len(df)-1)]]

df.insert(0, symbol, first_column)
print(df.to_csv(index=False))
```

Output

```
symbol,date,EPS,Revenue
AAPL,2019-09-28,11.97,
,2018-09-29,12.01,2.65595e+11
,2017-09-30,,
,2016-09-24,,2.15639e+11
,2015-09-26,9.28,2.33715e+11
,2014-09-27,6.49,1.82795e+11
,2013-09-28,40.03,1.7091e+11
,2012-09-29,44.64,1.56508e+11
,2011-09-24,28.05,1.08249e+11
,2010-09-25,15.41,65225000000.0
,2009-09-26,1.317,42905000000.0
```

---

#### Original answer

The issue here lies in your JSON data. Your data is structured in two column format: "symbol,financials". Perhaps you're trying to make a table from the data in financials? For example, see the following snippet.

```py
import pandas

print(pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(data["financials"]).to_csv(index=False))
```

Output

```
date,EPS,Revenue
2019-09-28,11.97,
2018-09-29,12.01,2.65595e+11
2017-09-30,,
2016-09-24,,2.15639e+11
2015-09-26,9.28,2.33715e+11
2014-09-27,6.49,1.82795e+11
2013-09-28,40.03,1.7091e+11
2012-09-29,44.64,1.56508e+11
2011-09-24,28.05,1.08249e+11
2010-09-25,15.41,65225000000.0
2009-09-26,1.317,42905000000.0
```

Comment: I've added an EDIT to my answer. Basically, just need to handle any sort of arbitrary json and add the symbol only to the first row and label the headers with "financials.EPS", etc.

Comment: this solution does not add `.financials`, it is also good that you try to use pandas methods and do not use unnecessary loops, it is simply slower and less elegant

Comment: I intentionally did not add the heading prefix or use pandas built-ins as doing either would make for smelly code, are no more efficient, and do not add clarity to the data.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
df = (pd.json_normalize(data, 'financials')
        .rename_axis(index='symbol')
        .add_prefix('financials.')
        .reset_index()
        .assign(symbol=lambda x: np.where(x.index==0, data['symbol'], ''))
        .fillna(''))
```

---

or

```
df = pd.read_json(data)
df = (df[['symbol']].join(pd.DataFrame(df['financials'].tolist()).fillna(''))
                    .assign(symbol = lambda x: x.loc[:,'symbol'].where(x.index==0,''))
                    .set_index('symbol')
                    .add_prefix('financials.')
                    .reset_index())
df.to_csv(index=False)
print(df)
```

---

```
   symbol financials.date financials.EPS financials.Revenue
0    AAPL      2019-09-28          11.97                   
1              2018-09-29          12.01        2.65595e+11
2              2017-09-30                                  
3              2016-09-24                       2.15639e+11
4              2015-09-26           9.28        2.33715e+11
5              2014-09-27           6.49        1.82795e+11
6              2013-09-28          40.03         1.7091e+11
7              2012-09-29          44.64        1.56508e+11
8              2011-09-24          28.05        1.08249e+11
9              2010-09-25          15.41      65225000000.0
10             2009-09-26          1.317      42905000000.0
```

Comment: That's awesome! I've accepted another answer but I think I'll be posting something else that is looking to do this for more arbitrary json...where there may be many more keys like "symbol", and keys that hold an array of integers, etc.

Comment: Thanks again! What if I don't know the keys in advance? 'financials' and 'symbol' might have a different key names. Also, how do I handle more keys...like if there's symbol and company name, etc?